# How do I get my chip to appear on the top right corner of this app in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am currently working on my local environment to create a chip that appears only while using the staging environment of our app. I am having trouble getting this chip - from material UI - to appear on the top right corner of the app (working on desktop ui). Let me know if you need more information! This is my .jsx file:

```
import React from 'react'
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip'

const StagingChip = () => (
    <>
      <div>
        <Chip label="Staging" color='info'/>
      </div>
    </>
  )

export default StagingChip
```

Comment: `margin-left: auto` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's with `position: fixed` solution:

```
import React from 'react'
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip'

const StagingChip = () => (
      <div style={{position: "fixed", top: 8, right: 8}}>
        <Chip label="Staging" color='info'/>
      </div>
  )

export default StagingChip
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to style the chip to have fixed position, and then assign top: 0 and right: 0

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

```css
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mock_chip{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.in_corner{
  /* you need to add position, top and right to the element that should be in corner */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="mock_chip in_corner">
    chip mock
  </div>
</main>
```

You can also do it directly inside of the `jsx` file:

- if you want to move the `div` element add the `style` prop to `div` `style={{position: 'fixed', top: 0, right: 0}}`
- and if you want to move just the `Chip`, then add `sx` prop to `Chip` `sx={{position: 'fixed', top: 0, right: 0}}`

Comment: Can i do this right inside the .jsx file?

Comment: Yes :D
If you want to move the div element add the `style` prop to div  `style={{position: 'fixed', top: 0, right: 0}}`,
and if you want to move just the Chip, then add `sx` prop to Chip `sx={{position: 'fixed', top: 0, right: 0}}`